# Tag badge color

Tags: bug, design, tag-badges

While looking at my recent badges, I discovered that when you put your cursor over a badge tag, the text become invisible.

A little research inside the `all.css` file confirmed the issue :

```
.badge-tag:hover{
    background:#eff0f1;
    color:#eff0f1
}
```

Should we set it to the non-hover color  (which is `#6a7177`), or set it to a slight darker one ?

Comment: Confirmed, On SO, for tag badges.

Comment: I didn't found that question while searching the issue (both with .css style name and color value), my question should be closed and the new informations about this issue added to the other one.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. No one is blaming you for not finding it. I only found it because I remember reading the question earlier today. :-)